# Are there any Android phones that allow Bluetooth PAN off the shelf?

Tags: bluetooth, hardware

I'm specifically looking for an off-the-shelf solution.

Without going into too much technical detail, I need to connect a phone via Bluetooth to a device and receive IP traffic from the device. Bluetooth PAN provides that functionality, but it seems to be disabled by default in most commercial Android phones. Short of recompiling the OS, are there phones available (specific models, or buying directly from the manufacturer etc) that allow Bluetooth PAN?

**edit:** I'm actually looking for any solution that would allow me to establish a network connection from the phone to the device. The device's onboard NIC doesn't allow it to be configured as a WAP.

Comment: This earned me a Tumbleweed... can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

Android 4.0 devices (or already 3.0?) allow this.

Both client and host PAN roles are supported (I guess this was deliberately introduced by Google for UMTS-less tablets).

On the PAN host: Enable bluetooth tethering in the settings
On each device: Pair with the host and enable "Internet access" in the bluetooth device's tab:

[image: Bluetooth pairing to a Nokia from a Nexus S running 4.0.4]