# Do all current Android versions require rooting for bluetooth tethering (PAN)?

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, bluetooth-tethering

Looking at apps like ["Wireless Tether for Root Users"](https://market.android.com/details?id=android.tether) and ["tether Blu"](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androidactivity.tetherBlu), and questions like ["Are there any Android phones that allow Bluetooth PAN off the shelf?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12572/are-there-any-android-phones-that-allow-bluetooth-pan-off-the-shelf) it seems that Android would require rooting for providing Bluetooth tethering (PAN).

However another app ["PdaNet 3.02"](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pn.helper) boasts that it *"supports both USB Tether or Bluetooth DUN"* and *"does not require rooting"*. Also, coming from Symbian it would seem weird that what I've considered a basic feature isn't available without hacks.

I would try the PdaNet app myself, but the unfortunately it is incompatible with my phone, which is still running Android 2.2.

So what's the deal? Is bluetooth tethering available in 2.3 or will it require rooting even then?

*(Apparently in some countries tethering as a concept is restricted, and thus blocked from phones. However, I live in Finland so my phone is not tethering-restricted in this way, e.g. Wi-Fi tethering (creating a Wi-Fi hotspot) is a feature available for me out-of-the-box.)*

Answer (score 3):

My Galaxy S with 2.3.3 has no option for bluetooth tethering, but my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet running 3.1 has such an option. I am not entirely sure if the option comes from stock Android because it doesn't get listed [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#3.0). So I assume that it's an modification from Lenovo.

2.3 will require root for bluetooth tethering if there where no modifications by the manufacturer and I think bluetooth tethering hasn't found the way in **stock** android yet.

Answer (score 1):

For Android 2.2 I belive you do need to root the device to install a tethering app. However, Android 2.3 does have tethering over wi-fi or USB built but I find that it doesn't work that well so I have still rooted it and installed the app. I don't know if the problem with the built in tethering is a problem with my phone or android overall so you might find the built in version works fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, it seems Android 2.2 also has tethering over Wi-Fi (or USB) built-in, without rooting, unless restricted by country or phone provider regulations. Well, at least my phone does have both Wi-Fi and USB tethering built in, and it's running Android 2.2. That's exactly why I find it so strange that *Bluetooth* tethering would suddenly require rooting.