# Reverse tethering Android to Mac via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, macos, reverse-tether, bluetooth-tethering

I'm trying to let my Android (4.1.1) phone use my Mac's (10.8.2) wifi connection via Bluetooth. This is what I've tried:

- Paired devices successfully; PAN interface created on the Mac
- Enabled Internet Sharing from Wifi to Bluetooth PAN
- `adb shell`; `pand -c XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

After running `pand`, I briefly see that Bluetooth connection established, but it quickly drops after a second. Running `adb logcat`, this is what I see:

```
I/pand    ( 4876): Bluetooth PAN daemon version 4.93
I/pand    ( 4876): Connecting to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
D/BluetoothEventLoop(  300): Device property changed: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX property: Connected value: true
E/pand    ( 4876): Connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX failed. Permission denied(13)
D/BluetoothEventLoop(  300): Device property changed: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX property: Connected value: false
```

How do I get this to work successfully?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is in this answer.

[Are there any Android phones that allow Bluetooth PAN off the shelf?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12572/are-there-any-android-phones-that-allow-bluetooth-pan-off-the-shelf/29089#29089)

Having enabled internet sharing via bluetooth on the Mac, which doesn't need command line on recent versions at least, pair the devices and then go to bluetooth settings on the Android device, select the Mac, tap the settings gear and enable it for internet access.

It seems to matter that the internet sharing is enabled before pairing the devices, but that may have been a one-off.

The reason I needed to do this, is for hotel internet access where you have to pay *per device*, and the signal was poor so only my laptop could get a decent connection.  Now Mac, iPad and 2 android tablets all online, so kids happy :-)